# jQuery Cycle plugin IE6/7 issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I've implemented a slideshow using the Cycle plugin, which is working in all browsers except IE6&7, where the images just show up in a list, and the #page_copy div is not hiding.  I've been going through the code all day without any luck, and not exactly sure how or what I should be looking for.

What would be the best way to go about debugging this issue? I know that the #page_copy div is hiding when I remove the rest of the code, and I've tried the reverse (which had no result)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        jQuery.fn.fadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) { 
            return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback); 
        };


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#page_copy').hide();
            $('a#info_close_button').click(function() {
                $('#page_copy').fadeOut(200);
                return false;
            });
            $('a#info_button').click(function() {
                $('#page_copy').fadeToggle(200);
                return false;
            });
        });


        $(window).load(function() {
            // vertically center single image
            var $image_cnt = $("#images > img").size();
            if($image_cnt < 2) {
                var $single_img = $("#images").children(':first-child');
                var h = $single_img.height();
                $single_img.css({
                    marginTop: (620 - h) / 2,
                });
                $(".next").css("display","none");
                $(".prev").css("display","none");
            }
        });


        // wait until images have loaded before starting cycle
        $(window).load(function() {
            // front image rotator
            $('#images').cycle({ 
                fx: 'fade',
                speed:  300, 
                next:   '.next', 
                prev:   '.prev',
                containerResize: 0,
                timeout:  0, 
                delay:   -2000,
                before: onBefore
            });

        }); 

        // hide all but the first image when page loads
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#images img:gt(0)').hide();
        });

        // callback fired when each slide transition begins
        function onBefore(curr,next,opts) {
            var $slide = $(next);
            var w = $slide.width();
            var h = $slide.height();
            $slide.css({
                marginTop: (620 - h) / 2,
                marginLeft: (650 - w) / 2
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get why you have multiple `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`..

Maybe you should just try and place everything in a single `$(document).ready` block.

Additionally move the definition of `function onBefore(...)` at the very start of the `<script>` tag. Directly before the `jQuery.fn.fadeToggle` code.

Try also removing the unneeded comma at the end of this piece of code

```
$single_img.css({
    marginTop: (620 - h) / 2, //<---- remove comma
});
```

And also remove this unneeded semi-colon

```
function onBefore(curr,next,opts) {...}; //<--- unneeded
```

Comment: thanks for the tips jitter. I removed that comma and semi-colon, and moved all the code in to one $(document).ready and one $(window).load, but still have the same issues. There needs to be both otherwise the image size isn't evaluated in time if everything is in a doc.ready